# loading javascript into ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to import the following three js libraries. They all work except for crossfilter.js. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import jinja2
from IPython.display import display, Javascript, HTML

%%javascript
require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.8/d3.min',
        crossfilter: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.7/crossfilter.min',
        dc: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.0/dc.min'
    }
});

dc = jinja2.Template(
"""

require(["d3","crossfilter","dc"], function(d3,crossfilter,dc) {    

    console.log(d3);
    console.log(crossfilter);
    console.log(dc);    

});    
""")

display(Javascript(dc.render()))
```

### Output I am getting:

Object
Undefined
Object

Answer (score 1):

Crossfilter does not (yet) support requireJS:

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/issues/114

The ticket shows how to use a shim config to load it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it actually works if you omit the crossfilter input... require(["d3","dc"], function(d3,dc)